# Frequent boot-up hangs Win7 HP Elitebook 2730p

Tags: windows-7, hp-elitebook

I have strange problem when booting up my HP Elitebook 2730p--

Many times, upon turning on, I get the HP logo, and then the computer seems to hang, and I have a blank screen; even the HDD LED does not blink. The Power is on, the fan keeps running.

The I have to press Ctrl-Alt-Del once, or twice (and sometimes repeat a few more times), and then things just seem to click, the HDD LED starts blinking, and the computer starts as if nothing happened.

This problem also happens when I put the laptop into Hibernate. Press the power on switch, HP logo comes on, and then nothing. A few Ctrl-Alt-Dels later and then something seems to click and the "Resuming Windows" logo starts off.

Other than this, I have no problems with this tablet PC. It just seems like that on start-up the system is unable to find the boot-up files or something.

Any ideas? suggestions?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely a hardware than a software problem. Bring it to service center. A faulty power supply, faulty mainboard and faulty harddrive could be the culprit. If I were you I would try to backup the data and take it to service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the native troubleshooter (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Troubleshooting-in-Windows),  but I agree with Bubu, it may be a hardware issue.